# Have app video display in google play store

Tags: android, google-play

So I want to display a video preview of my app in its google play store listing. I am able to add screen shots but I cannot drag videos into the boxes where I put the images. Any idea on how I can display my video?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a field just below *High Resolution Application Icon*.

[image: video link specs]

Comment: Make sure to use the full URL (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=myvideoid) rather than the shortened version. I found the shortened version worked in the Play Store App, but not when viewed from the web.

Answer (score 2):

There is a separate field "Promo Video" which accepts a link to a YouTube video.